# Прозрачные отступы у шрифтов

Tags: html, css

хочу обратиться к вам за помощью. Как убрать эти прозрачные отступы у шрифтов?
Я обвел их красным цветов на скриншоте
п.с. текст просто выделен мышкой, чтобы показать где находятся эти отступы[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: там обнулять их не надо, потому что они изначально не заданы. у меня специально открыта консоль, чтобы это было видно

Comment: ну раз авторитетно, то давайте поговорим о том, что отступы применяются к блокам, а не к самому шрифту

Comment: я обнулял все padding. вы понимаете, что я сейчас говорю об отступах самого шрифта, а не блока? если я обнулю padding то я дальнейшем не смогу сделать отступы внутри самого блока. прежде чем советовать глупости, сто раз подумайте своей авторитетной головой!

Answer (score 1):

Возможно если задашь элементам display: block то все отступы будут задаваться правильно. Но скорее всего это не отступы а свободная область шрифтов и их никак не уберёшь.

Answer (score 0):

Каждый браузер имеет свои встроенные стили

Это касается и `inline-block` и `block` и `flex` и всех остальных техник, потому есть reset и normalize и тому подобные стили которые всё это убирают ...т.е убирают стандартное поведение всех браузеров

На скринах я показал разную степень обнуления с применением разных стилей

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: никаких изменений нет. https://i.imgur.com/z4p2kWv.png https://i.imgur.com/doVLJ4w.png

Comment: @Никита ты видишь я показал что отступы разные ?и применял я разные стили ...10px 16px...19px  заметил ?

Comment: я вижу, что ширина менялась, но я не вижу за счет использования каких стилей это было сделано

Comment: @Никита поставь для тега `a`  вот это `vertical-align:middle;`

Comment: @Никита https://jsfiddle.net/lenskyuser/1oL09os2/5/